# Rock, Paper, Scissors Game not adding

Tags: javascript

I realize this is yet another rock, paper, scissors game, but I'm a little stuck. I need help on this one part then I want to figure out the rest.

I had this running 5 loops and now it runs 3. Also, I can't get the playerScore and computerScore to add each round (i.e. player wins twice in a row, then playerScore should equal 2) Below is my code, I've tried many options and have scoured the internet for a couple days trying to figure this out. If I have any syntax errors then please let me know and I'll fix before posting again. Thank you!

```
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
  const cptchoice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return cptchoice[randomNumber];
}

function playerPlay() {
  const playerPrompt = prompt("Paper, Scissors, or Rock");
  return playerPrompt[0].toUpperCase() + playerPrompt.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

var playRound = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const playerSelection = playerPlay();
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    switch (playerSelection + computerSelection) {
      case "PaperRock":
      case "RockScissors":
      case "ScissorsPaper":
        console.log("Win");
        return playerScore + 1;
        break;
      case "PaperScissors":
      case "RockPaper":
      case "ScissorsRock":
        console.log("Lose");
        return computerScore + 1;
        break;
      case "PaperPaper":
      case "RockRock":
      case "ScissorsScissors":
        console.log("Tie");
        console.log(playerScore + 0);
    }
    console.log(playerScore);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `return` in your switch case statement, which is causing the function `playRound()` to finish executing. If you just remove `return` and add to the score only, it will go all the way through.

```js
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
  const cptchoice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return cptchoice[randomNumber];
}

function playerPlay() {
  const playerPrompt = prompt("Paper, Scissors, or Rock");
  return playerPrompt[0].toUpperCase() + playerPrompt.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

var playRound = function() {
  const playerSelection = playerPlay();
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  switch (playerSelection + computerSelection) {
    case "PaperRock":
    case "RockScissors":
    case "ScissorsPaper":
      console.log("Win");
      playerScore += 1;
      break;
    case "PaperScissors":
    case "RockPaper":
    case "ScissorsRock":
      console.log("Lose");
      computerScore += 1;
      break;
    case "PaperPaper":
    case "RockRock":
    case "ScissorsScissors":
      console.log("Tie");
  }
  console.log(playerScore);
};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  playRound();
}
```

Comment: Anything thank you so much! This works perfectly. I really appreciate the help. Have a great day!